# No data when rendering ga:userGender in my app using Reporting API V4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am creating simple app that renders Google Analytics data in view.
By using multiple examples I have set up everything. Few queries work without problem, but I can't retrieve info about audience, especially, userGender.

I don't receive any error message in view, but just "No data" message.

**My code in view:**

```
    <div id="chart-2-container"></div>
    <div id="view-selector-2-container"></div>

    <script>
         var viewSelector2 = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector-2-container'
         });

           viewSelector2.execute();




        var dataChart2 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({

             query: {
               metrics: 'ga:users',
               dimensions: 'ga:userGender',
               'start-date': '60daysAgo',
               'end-date': 'today',
               'max-results': 6,
           },
             chart: {
               container: 'chart-2-container',
               type: 'PIE',
               options: {
               width: '100%',
               pieHole: 4/9
             }
       }
 });

     viewSelector2.on('change', function(ids) {
       dataChart2.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
     });


</script>
```

Note: I just showed code for that query that doesn't work, I have other ones that work great (See attached pic):

[image]

I tried the same query in [query-explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and received no data message too.

In [Audience - Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=audience&jump=ga_useragebracket)  under **ga:userGender** dimension isn't requered any metrics, but in Query Explorer they required metric (See in above example).

What could be possible problem and solution for this?
Thanks.